# ActionScript: Constructor for Value Object classes

Tags: actionscript, value-objects

Is it OK to use the constructor to set properties for a value object class or must I use dot notation and set each one, one-by-one?

I recently read an article that was saying I should do it one-by-one as value objects should only contain properties and went on to say using the constructor is not OK (best-practice wise).

Code:
("not OK")

> var employee=new
>   Employee(firstName,lastName,age);

("OK")

> var employee=new Employee();
>   employee.firstName=firstName;
>   employee.lastName=lastName;
>   employee.age=age;

What's your take on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've *never* heard anyone say that using a constructor to construct an object is a bad idea. The only case that I can think of is if the list of elements to be initialized can be changed (add/removed) and therefore changing the API of the object (which *is* bad, especially when developing libraries). In this case, I'd *still* use the constructor, but I'd pass in an initialization object (which contains `n` parameters) rather than modifying the function signature.

The statement "it's bad practice to use the constructor to construct the object" (paraphrasing) just doesn't make sense to me :P